# How do I install android libraries with Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android app development, and I want to install [this library](https://github.com/klinker41/android-smsmms) with my app.

I'm using Android Studio, but I can't find the right option to let me install the library.

What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just insert the following :

```
compile 'com.klinkerapps:android-smsmms:+'
```

In your app.gradle / dependencies

Answer (score 1):

You need to read about Gradle. Hope it'll help you

[Gradle tutorial](http://rominirani.com/2014/08/19/gradle-tutorial-part-6-android-studio-gradle/)